# override variable declared inside class

Tags: python

I want to override variable which is declared inside of a class `Bank`, as you can see in the code below, I've tow inits, `chosen_word` and `word`, the first one, is declared when calling the function, the second one `word` is declared inside of a function, what I want to do is to override that `word` but python returns an error saying : `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'`

```py
class Bank:
    def __init__(self,chosen_word,word):
        self.chosen_word = chosen_word
        self.word = word
    
    def choose_theme(self):
        if chosen_word == "World":
            word = random.choice(math)
            splitten_word = split(word)
            elements = ['_'.format(element) for element in splitten_word]
            print(elements)
        elif chosen_word == "Hello":
            word = random.choice(tech)
            splitten_word = split(word)
            elements = ['_'.format(element) for element in splitten_word]
            print(elements)
chosen_word = input("choose word:" + str(temebi))
levani = Bank(chosen_word)
levani.choose_theme()
```

Comment: Constructor of `Bank` expect two arguments: `chosen_word` and `word`. You pass a single argument and get exception.

Comment: You are missing one argument `word` which you passed to constructor method. Pass it by making instance as `Bank(chosen_word,word)` by taking `word` as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructur demands for two parameters `chosen_word` and `word`

```
def __init__(self,chosen_word,word):
```

Here you are not providing `word`

```
levani = Bank(chosen_word)
```

That's the error message.
You need to provide this argument or modify your constructor p.e.:

```
def __init__(self,chosen_word, word=None):
  if word == None:
    self.chosen_word = chosen_word
    self.word = chosen_word
  else:
    self.chosen_word = chosen_word
    self.word = word
```